# Android MediaProjection can record objects(only activity)?

Tags: android, screen-recording, android-mediaprojection

From the lollipop version MediaProjection API was released and it became much easier to take a screenshot or record a screen.

BUT I would like to record the screen which I want to. 
It's more like "object recording" not the whole screen.
For example, when the user does some actions like pulling down the notification bar or when the push notification messages are popped up on the screen, I want to exclude those cases in my recording.

Is there any other API that supports what I want? or simply MediaProjection API has this kind of functionality already?

Comment: did you get any help ?